# Identifying a 'straight' (from Poker) using Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python function that will recognize a 'straight' from Poker. My code works and will recognize a straight, but only gives me the numbers in the straight, not the suit. Further the rest of the code is written with a specific format for the cards, i.e. python dictionary format, and therefore I need this function to also return the cards in this format.

My code so far:

```
cards_numbers=[11, 5, 6, 4, 2, 4, 3]
cards_dct={'11D': (11, 'D'), '5S': (5, 'S'), '6S': (6, 'S'), '4D': (4, 'D'), '2H': (2, 'H'), '4C': (4, 'C'), '3D': (3, 'D')}

def is_straight():
    straight=False
    numbers=set(numbers)
    print numbers
    sorted_numbers=sorted(numbers)
    for i in range(len(sorted_numbers)):
        if sorted_numbers[i]-sorted_numbers[i-1]==1 and sorted_numbers[i-1]-sorted_numbers[i-2]==1 and sorted_numbers[i-2]-sorted_numbers[i-3]==1 and sorted_numbers[i-3]-sorted_numbers[i-4]==1:
            straight=True                
            highest_in_straight=sorted_numbers[i]
    straight_numbers=range(highest_in_straight-4,highest_in_straight+1)
    print straight_numbers 
    print self.cards_dct
    for i in cards_dct.keys():
        for j in numbers:
            pattern=re.compile(str(j)+'[DSHC]')
            print re.findall(pattern,i)
```

The above code will identify a straight but I'm having difficulty getting back the numbers and the suit from the dictionary. So my question is, how can I get my code to to return a dictionary, containing only elements within the straight (excluding the duplicate 4's) ?

```
desired_outout={'5S': (5, 'S'), '6S': (6, 'S'), '2H': (2, 'H'), '4C': (4, 'C'), '3D': (3, 'D')}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Barmar, I would suggest using a list of dictionaries to represent your hand.

```
hand = [{'rank':10, 'suit':'Spade'}, {'rank':11, 'suit':'Heart'}, ...]
```

Then you could check if there's a straight by creating a set of ranks (which will eliminate duplicates). If the difference between the max rank and min rank plus one is equal to the size of the set and the set is the size of the hand, you have a straight. It's a reduction to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Implementing this in Python is pretty trivial.

Here's to verify it works given a straight:

```
>>> hand = [{'rank':10, 'suit':'Spade'}, {'rank':11, 'suit':'Heart'}, {'rank':9, 'suit':'Spade'}, {'rank':12, 'suit':'Spade'}, {'rank':8, 'suit':'Spade'}]
>>> rank_set = { card['rank'] for card in hand }
>>> rank_set
set([8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
>>> is_straight = (max(rank_set) - min(rank_set) + 1) == len(hand) and len(rank_set) == len(hand)
>>> is_straight
True
```

and now to check if it isn't a straight:

```
>>> hand = [{'rank':10, 'suit':'Spade'}, {'rank':11, 'suit':'Heart'}, {'rank':9, 'suit':'Spade'}, {'rank':12, 'suit':'Spade'}, {'rank':7, 'suit':'Spade'}]
>>> rank_set = { card['rank'] for card in hand }
>>> is_straight = (max(rank_set) - min(rank_set) + 1) == len(hand) and len(rank_set) == len(hand)
>>> is_straight
False
```

Now to make it a function:

```
def is_a_straight(hand):
    rank_set = { card['rank'] for card in hand }
    rank_range = max(rank_set) - min(rank_set) + 1
    return rank_range == len(hand) and len(rank_set) == len(hand)
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a dictionary to represent the hand, use a list of lists or a list of dicts, e.g.

```
cards = [{rank: 5, suit: 'S'}, {rank: 11, suit: 'D'}, ...]
```

Then your `is_straight` function can work with this, by sorting it based on the `rank` element and then testing whether `sorted_numbers[i].rank == sorted_numbers[i-1].rank + 1` and so on. When it detects that there's a straight, it can simply use the cards in `sorted_cards`.

Comment: Might be worth noting that for small hands, one could use selection sort as an alternative to an `O(nlogn)` sort because for small `n`, `n^2` is more performant.

Comment: @erip For small hands, the efficiency of sorting is negligible.

Comment: Tell that to bogo sort.

Answer (score 4):

Like with most examples of poker (or blackjack) games used as programming assignments, the real solution is to fix your data structure. Trying to deal with a card without creating an object for it is really hard, it turns out. You can manage with a tuple, but it's often useful to use Enums for rank and suit if you do. Let's go that route (if only because Enums are more fun than classes!)

It looks like you're using Python2, which is a shame. I ***strongly*** recommend you upgrade to Python3, but if you can't for some reason then you should install [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) from the command line with:

```
$ pip install enum34
```

`enum34` is the backport of Py3.4's `enum` module to Python2. Then you can do:

```
import collections
from enum import IntEnum

Suits = IntEnum("Suits", "spades hearts clubs diamonds")
Ranks = IntEnum("Ranks", "ace two three four five six seven eight nine ten jack queen king")

Card = collections.namedtuple("Card", "rank suit")
```

Then your card initialization becomes:

```
# 2 of spades, 5 of clubs, King of hearts
cardsinfo = [(2, "spades"), (5, "clubs"), (13, "hearts")]
hand = [Card(Ranks(r), Suits[s]) for r,s in cardsinfo]
```

and your straight detection looks  like:

```
def is_straight(hand):
    hand.sort(key=operator.attrgetter("rank"))
    start = hand[0].rank
    straight = [Card(r, None) for r in range(start, start+6)]
    return all(got.rank == want.rank for got,want in zip(hand, straight))
```

The nice thing about this method is that it can be easily used to make many checks

```
def is_flush(hand):
    the_suit = hand[0].suit
    return all(c.suit == the_suit for c in hand)

def is_straightflush(hand):
    return is_straight(hand) and is_flush(hand)

def is_royalflush(hand):
    s = hand[0].suit
    royal = [Card(Ranks.ace, s)] + [Card(Ranks(r), s) for r in range(10, 14)]
    return royal == sorted(hand, key=operator.attrgetter("rank"))

def is_pair(hand):
    ranks = collections.Counter(map(operator.attrgetter("rank"), hand))
    return ranks.most_common(1)[1] == 2

def is_three_of_kind(hand):
    ranks = collections.Counter(map(operator.attrgetter("rank"), hand))
    return ranks.most_common(1)[1] == 3

def is_four_of_kind(hand):
    ranks = collections.Counter(map(operator.attrgetter("rank"), hand))
    return ranks.most_common(1)[1] == 4

def is_two_pair(hand):
    ranks = collections.Counter(map(operator.attrgetter("rank"), hand))
    pairs = ranks.most_common(2)
    return pairs[0][1] == 2 and pairs[1][1] == 2

def is_full_house(hand):
    ranks = collections.Counter(map(operator.attrgetter("rank"), hand))
    triplet, pair = ranks.most_common(2)
    return triplet[1] == 3 and pair[1] == 2
```